# How do I filter out the row with the nested list but not those with the tibble?

Tags: r, nested, tidyverse

I have the data frame with nested data in the data column.

```
nested_df <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  add_row(
    Species = "Smurfs", 
    data = list(list())
  )
```

How do I exclude the rows where the data does is an empty list?

I have tried things like:

```
nested_df %>% 
  filter(!map_lgl(data, is.list))
```

However, they seem to look at the class of the column, not what is in the column.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a logical vector with `lengths`

```
library(dplyr)
nested_df %>%
   filter(lengths(data) > 0)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    data             
  <chr>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

---

Or another option is to check if the `list` element is a tibble

```
library(purrr)
nested_df %>% 
   filter(map_lgl(data, is_tibble))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    data             
  <chr>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

---

Or to do test for multiple conditions

```
nested_df %>% 
    filter(lengths(data) > 0 & map_lgl(data, is_tibble))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    data             
  <chr>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I just have to wait 8 minutes before I can accept the answer ;-)